# Autocomplete doesn't work on Prestashop 1.6 custom module

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, prestashop

I want to add the jquery ui module autocomplete on a input text.
In my controller I add this line :

`$this->context->controller->addJqueryUi('ui.autocomplete');`

In my template, a test textbox :

`test auto complete <input type="text" id="testautocomplete">`

In my JS called by my template :

```
var dataSrc = ["australia", "austria", "antartica", "argentina", "algeria"];
    $("#testautocomplete").autocomplete({
        source:dataSrc
    });
```

But that don't work.
I see in my source page this :

`<input type="text" id="testautocomplete" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input">`

I tried to add this in my JS
`$('#testautocomplete').attr("autocomplete", "on");`

But still doesn't work.

Please help ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could explain, but I think could be more useful for you take an idea from the module [ps_searchbar](https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_searchbar) in PS 1.7, check the file `ps_searchbar.js` which will serve as a guide to apply in your module.
If you have troubles loading the library, you can check the `hookHeader` of the file `ps_searchbar.php`.

Comment: thanks, but I'm on ps 1.6. I saw that PS use a plugin and not the jquery ui. I tried to add the jquery ui autocomplete file in hookheader but for now I have some JS errors.